# Partial insensitive search with drupal 7 and apache solr 3.x

Tags: xml, apache, search, solr, drupal-7

I'm configuring an apache solr based search on a drupal 7 environment.
Search is using apache solr, and is working, but not in the way I would like.

When I enter something like "staff", I would like result such as "Staff", "Staffing", "staffing".

I restarted apache server, clear drupal caches, clear indexes, and re-indexed all content, but it's not working (i have only result such as "staff" full word).

So, I updated schema.xml to include some edgeNGramFilter as suggested on other stackoverflow threads, then it's strange, I have 1 result more, which contains "staffing".
But if I click on "Did you mean 'staffing' ? " then I have a few 'staffing' results more.

Can anybody please help ?

```
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/> 
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="100" side="front" />
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="100" side="back" />    
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>  
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="100" side="front" />
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="100" side="back" />    
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is the configuration so complicated ??? with so many filters ???
You can start One by One trying to match individual conditions.

If you want to search for  "staff" and would like result such as "Staff", "Staffing", "estaffing".

1. `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` - This will enable you to tokenized on whitespace
2. For matching staff with Staff have `LowerCaseFilterFactory` to make search case insensitive
3. To match staff with staffing, check for stemmer which will reduce the words to the root. e.g. `SnowballPorterFilterFactory` in the configuration, you would need to test the stemming.
4. For staff to estaffing match, this can be handle by only synonyms filter. Index time snonyms are preferred with expand option so query time is not needed.

Comment: This config is the default one I took from apache solr module coming with drupal. As search was 'partially' working, my idea was to edit this to reach my goal. Anyway, as I'm quite new to solr, maybe it's a better idea to start one by one you right. Will question you later if I need assistance in the step you described above. thx.

Comment: i would prefer not have the edgegrams at query time. Also remember the order is important for filtering. SnowballPorterFilterFactory is before EdgeNGramFilterFactory so estaffing would not be stemmed.

Answer (score 0):

For the ones interested, finally, based on comment from Jayendra @Jayendra, this works:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="100" side="front" />
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="100" side="back" />    
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>         
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>  
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```